# ListView not refreshed after item get deleted

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

```
  ListView listViewUpdate;
  ListAdapter adapter;

  listViewUpdate.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> p, View v, final int po, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = EditDetails.get(po);
                iD=clickedItem.get(Configs.TAG_ID);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Delete");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                        delete(iD);
                        listViewUpdate.setAdapter(adapter);
                        ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }

                );
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return edit_details;
    }
```

Item get deleted but the listView not refreshing . Is it a must to have customBaseAdapter? Data were retrieved from MySQL and I get the tutorial from [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/) as he only use List adapter. Thanks

Comment: ListAdapter adapter; is it outside onCreate of your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to do like this to refresh the list View  after deleting the current position from the Array

```
listDO.clear();  
    listDO.addAll(getyourList()); 

     if (rowAdapter == null) {   
         rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(listDO);   
         listView.setAdapter(rowAdapter);   
        } else {   
         rowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        }
```

Comment: can you explain more on this ?

Comment: @JohnJoe: you need to remove all views in the list view and initialise a new adapter and set the new adapter to the list view